# C# convert string to byte and ouput as string

Tags: c#, string, type-conversion, byte

I want to convert a `string` to `byte` and output it as `string`.

example: 
string: `255`
output: `0xFF`

```
richTextBox1.AppendText(textBox1.Text + " || " + Convert.ToBytes(textBox1.Text) + "\n");
```

I am getting `System.Byte[]` instead of the value.

Comment: I think you are saying you want to convert a string consisting entirely of decimal digits that represents a numeric value from 0 to 255 to a string that represents that value in hexadecimal (uppercase) with a "0x" prefix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no implementation for an array to do that. You'll have to write your own. Something like the code below:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
            string output = string.Empty;
            foreach (byte item in bytes)
            {
                output += Convert.ToString(item, 16).ToUpper().PadLeft(2,'0');

            }
            Console.WriteLine(output);
            //or using string.Format
            bytes = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 14, 15, 16 };
             output = string.Empty;
            foreach (byte item in bytes)
            {
                output = string.Format("{0},{1:X}", output, item);

            }
            Console.WriteLine(output);
```